# MySql How to Merge two columns in one column Such that second column ouput goes uder first column in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How to Merge two columns in one column Such that second column ouput goes uder first column in multiple rows without using UNION in single query.

for Eg:

```
column1 column2 
1          3
2          4
```

expected OP:

```
 column1 
      1
      2
      3
      4
```

Comment: Are column values unique: over a column? over the whole table?

Comment: yes all column values unique

Comment: Why can't you use UNION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without using UNION in single query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN t00.id = t01.id
                     THEN t1.column1
                     ELSE t2.column2 
                     END all_values
FROM       ( SELECT column1 id 
             FROM test
             ORDER BY 1
             LIMIT 2 ) t00
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MIN(column1) id
             FROM test ) t01
CROSS JOIN test t1
CROSS JOIN test t2
ORDER BY 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=261225c2051a1ae53928563969eb368c)

The table must have at least 2 rows.

Applicable for 5.x MySQL version.

Answer (score 1):

`union all` is the right approach:

```
select column1 as col
from t
union all
select column2 
from t
order by col;
```

You can also use a `cross join` with the `union all` in a subquery:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then column1 else column2 end) as col
from t cross join
     (select row_number() over () as seqnum
      from t
      limit 2
     ) tt
order by col;
```

Comment: The conditions of the question are that one cannot use UNION. I don't know why.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . I updated the answer.  I think it is important to state that `union all` is probably the right way to approach the problem in MySQL.

Comment: I agree `union all` is the right approach. `union` would also work, since the OP stated the values are unique.

Comment: @manoj . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It seems like the simplest answer.